# Can't access JSON data returned from backend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I make an AJAX request and I get back a response saved to a data variable.

My controller:

```
def retrieve
  data = params[:data]
  @question = Question.find_by(id: params[:question_id])
  @choices = @question.choices
  results = []
  for d in data
    if Choice.find_by(id: d).correct
      results << d
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      render json: {
        choices: @choices.to_json(only: [:id,:correct]),
        results: results,
        message: "success"
        }
      }
  end
end
```

The response:

```
Object {choices: "[{"id":1,"correct":true},{"id":2,"correct":false}]", results: Array[1], message: "success"}
```

I'm getting value undefined where there should be a value.

```
data.choices[0].id -> returns undefined
```

Comment: the json response not recognizing the value of choices as array instead it recongnize it as string. I think you should try the following use `as_json` instead of  `to_json`

Comment: it worked thanks! bt why this error??

Comment: check out this [link](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/) to understand the difference

Comment: @MoustafaSallam - Sorry, did not read those comments before posting the answer. Please post an answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: @BroiSatse not a big deal, keep your answer. it doesn't matter

Comment: @MoustafaSallam - I will insist. :) You spotted that quite quickly and we need good answerers here with appropriate privileges.

Comment: guys put an answer to mark it as correct ;p

Comment: @BroiSatse thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as_json` instead of `to_json`

Your code should be

```
@choices.as_json(only: [:id,:correct])
```

instead of

```
@choices.to_json(only: [:id,:correct])
```

For further information about difference between `as_json` and `to_json` please checkout this [link](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)

Simply as_json works better with complex datatypes like `activerecord objects`

Comment: To add a little bit more - `to_json` uses `as_json` internally. The main difference between those two methods is that former returns a json string, while latter returns a hash.